# How inside javascript create script element and inside this element make some function?

Tags: javascript, html

I have like this javascript code:

```
<script>
   window.onload = function() {
      var heaad = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
      var script = document.createElement("script");
      head.appendChild(script);
      script.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
   }
</script>
```

How insert some function inside created **script** element.
Like this:

```
window.onload = function() {
   alert("Some text");
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of adding an `onload` function dynamically?

Comment: you can try set [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.innerHTML) or `innerText` for your created script element

Comment: It doesn't make sense to put a function "in a script tag".  Just run your code.

Comment: sounds like an [x-y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378)...explain your intentions in more detail